# How to stop live activity time from rounding down

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit, dynamic-island

I have a live activity with a timer and when `isLuminanceReduced` is true, the timer rounds down.

How do I get my live activity to stay at `40:00` when the timer is paused at `40:00` instead of `39:--`

```
struct TimerTextView: View {
    let range = Date()...Date().addingTimeInterval(1800)
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(timerInterval: range, pauseTime: range.upperBound)
    }
}
```

[image: Display on 1] [image: Luminance reduced 2]

Comment: two `Date()` you're using when initial the range are not the same date. try `let date = Date(); let range = date...date.addingTimeInterval(1800)`

Comment: that was an intersting idea but unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```
    struct TimerTextView: View {
        let range = Date()...Date().addingTimeInterval(1800)
        let pauseTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(1800).rounded(.up, toNearest: 60) //Round up to the nearest minute
        
        var body: some View {
            Text(timerInterval: range, pauseTime: pauseTime)
        }
    }
```

if it won't, maybe you had any writing mistakes?

Comment: i'm not sure what `.rounded(.up, toNearest: 60)` is but in theory this works but i'd like to pause my timer whenever, not just to the nearest minute.